# Google Analytics setup

Tags: android, google-analytics

Since Google's docs (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) don't explain any of this, I have to ask here:

1. What is a tracker?
2. That docs page has some trackers (APP_TRACKER, GLOBAL TRACKER, ECOMMERCE_TRACKER) being created as an example. Are these names hard coded? What is the difference between these? It says they are used for different purposes, but is the name the only difference?
3. What is PROPERTY_ID (specifically on that docs page)
4. What's a "screen view"? What does "sending a screen view" mean?

So, some really basic stuff that Google's docs should have explained in the first place. Not everybody is migrating from a previous version of GA, and these docs read more like "What's new" than a guide to implementing app analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Before you Begin' section has a link to [how to set up a property](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042508), which in turn has a link to [what a property is](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2649554):

> While you might think about your website or mobile app as a distinct, real-world piece of property, like a storefront, Google Analytics understands a property only as a resource associated with your tracking code. When you track a resource using Google Analytics, you include a property ID in the tracking code that you put on your web pages or in your app source code. Performance data, like number of users or screen views, for resources tagged with the same ID is collected into the corresponding property.

As per the [advanced configuration overview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#overview):

> The Google Analytics SDK for Android provides a `Tracker` class to set and send data to Google Analytics, and a `GoogleAnalytics` singleton that serves as an interface to the global configuration values of your implementation.

Trackers are associated with a property ID - what you call the `Tracker` variables is totally up to you.

Per [Using Multiple Trackers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/advanced#multiple-trackers):

> Mutiple trackers may be used in a single implementation, which can be useful for sending data to multiple properties

If you only need one property, then you probably only need one tracker.

The [Dev Guide for Screens](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/screens) have a good overview of what a screen is:

> Screens in Google Analytics represent content users are viewing within your app. The equivalent concept in web analytics is a pageview. Measuring screen views allows you to see which content is being viewed most by your users, and how they are navigating between different pieces of content.